# Integral with limit 1/(1+x^n)

Tags: integration, limits, lebesgue-integral

Is the following way to evaluate the integral correct?
$$\lim_{n \to\infty}\int_{(0,\infty)}\frac{1}{1+x^n}\mathrm{d}\lambda(x)=1$$
$$\lim_{n \to\infty}\int_{(0,\infty)}\frac{1}{1+x^n}\mathrm{d}\lambda(x)=\lim_{n \to\infty}\int_{(0,1)}\frac{1}{1+x^n}\mathrm{d}\lambda(x) \:+ \lim_{n \to\infty}\int_{(1,\infty)}\frac{1}{1+x^n}\mathrm{d}\lambda(x)$$
By MCT I get:
$$\lim_{n \to\infty}\int_{(1,\infty)}\frac{1}{1+x^n}\mathrm{d}\lambda(x)=  \int_{(1,\infty)} \lim_{n \to\infty}\frac{1}{1+x^n}\mathrm{d}\lambda(x)=0$$
And by DCT I get:
$$\lim_{n \to\infty}\int_{(0,1)}\frac{1}{1+x^n}\mathrm{d}\lambda(x) =\int_{(0,1)} \lim_{n \to\infty}\frac{1}{1+x^n}\mathrm{d}\lambda(x)=  \int_{(0,1)}\mathrm{d}\lambda(x)=1 $$

Comment: What is the role of $\lambda(x)$?

Comment: @Mikasa $\lambda$ is the lebesgue measure

Comment: Well, do you know the closed form formula for that integral for any positive $n$? It is $(\pi/n)\csc(\pi/n)$ so the limit should be $1$. The origin of that formula has been discussed extensively on this site before

Comment: @Silas Please show some effort

Comment: @Meowdog I would like to but the only thing I can show is that with MCT I can swap the limit with the integral on $(1,\infty)$ and then the limit of $\frac{1}{x^n+1}$ is zero

Comment: I have hinted strongly how to solve this: if you are supposed to not know anything about the integral itself and just use more general theory, then please say so in your question body.

Comment: @FShrike with the formula it‘s easy but since this is an exercise from an analysis exam where this formula wasn‘t given I‘m looking for a different method.

Comment: This is the kind of thing you need to edit into your post, as I said. The two downvotes and the lack of an answer is due to the extreme brevity of your post; you have said nothing, suggesting nothing about your goals, what you’ve been taught and what you think you have to do, etc.

Comment: @FShrike you‘re right. I‘ve edited the question.

Comment: @Silas Good. Your method looks correct to me

Comment: Since you've already know how to deal with $(1,+\infty)$, then $(0,1)$ isn't much harder. Indeed, pointwise on $(0,1)$ you have $x^n \to 0$, hence $\frac{1}{1+x^n} \to 1$. Moreover, $\frac{1}{1+x^n} \le 1$ on $(0,1)$, hence by Dominated Convergence Theorem, $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+x^n}d\lambda(x) \to \int_0^1 1 d\lambda(x) = 1$